# I want to open a 1GB file. Could any one guide me the editor that I can use?

Tags: file

I want to open a file having size 1 GB. Could any one guide me the editor that I can use?

I have tried it with Edit++ and Wordpad, but nothing help.

Comment: Which file type are you trying to open?

Comment: Use vim editor for this

Answer (score 0):

[010Editor](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/) on Windows will allow you to open big files in binary mode. Also you will be able to edit and search the text.